# Bind Node http to 127.0.0.1 with dynamic port

Tags: node.js

If you create a webserver and you don't specify any parameters to `listen`, it binds to all interfaces and picks a random port.

```js
server = http.createServer(async (request, response) => { ... });
server.listen();
```

I'd like to bind my embedded webserver strictly to the loopback interface so it's not accessible from other hosts, but I'd like to retain the random port selection behaviour.

I tried using an options object to specify just the host, but this resulted in an exception.  Is there any way to bind to the loopback interface on a random port?

```js
server.listen({ host: "127.0.0.1" });
```

Comment: just wondering - how would clients connect if port is random every time?

Comment: It's in a vscode extension that prints cross platform by spawning a browser with a url pointed at its embedded webserver that then serves the print job which is rendered as html. The process launching the browser knows what the port is and embeds it in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for UNIX-like operating systems, you'll get a random port if you pass `0` as a port number:

```
server.listen(0, '127.0.0.1', ...)
```

Comment: Works on Windows too. Thanks!